# Cant get $POST value back

Tags: php, html

On submit, i should receive an alert with the values but they come in blank. (I receive the alert etc but no values beside).

This alone is just a simple debug i like to use to ensure values are correct. With that said, i tried print_r and it came back with "playlistget = 1 and radioget = 1" but thats not correct as when i inspected the element on firefox they should come back at least one 0 or both depending on what i have showing.

To note: I am not displaying all code as the rest works perfectly its just this post -> show value i need help with.

With that said, when i inspect the elements on firefox the values show correctly so it is down to the post not working?

Submit:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    foreach($_POST['line'] as $alarm)
    {       
        if(!isset($alarm['remove']))
        {           
            $playlistget = $_POST['radioSelectedGetPlaylist'];
            $radioget = $_POST['radioSelectedGetRadio'];
            $rget = "playlistget = ".$playlistget." and radioget = ".$radioget."";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$rget');</script>"; //this alert shows but with no values beside but if i use print_r number 1 shows for values


            if (isset($_POST['radioSelectedGetRadio'])) //tried just if($post etc) but no point as im getting no value above in output
            {
                $foundRadioStationMessage = "Write radio station";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$foundRadioStationMessage');</script>";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['radioSelectedGetPlaylist']))
            {
                $foundplayStationMessage = "Write playlist";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$foundplayStationMessage');</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Posting:

```
<?PHP
echo"
    <td class=\"alarmvalue\" style=\"padding:2px 15px;\">
        <label class=\"switch-lightp2 well_\" onchange=\"checkSelectedScheduleType$line()\">";
            if ($radioresultvalue == "1") // if we find string webradio in cron file
            {
                echo "<input id=\"radioSelected$line\" name=\"radioSelectedGetRadio\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"1\">\n";
                $radioresultvalue = "0";
                $messagere = "radiovalue = 1 ";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$messagere');</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                $messageres = "radiovalue = 0 ";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$messageres');</script>";
                echo "<input id=\"radioSelected$line\" name=\"radioSelectedGetPlaylist\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"0\">\n";
            }
    echo"   <span><span>Playlist</span><span>Radio</span></span><a class=\"btn btn-primary\"></a>
        </label>
    </td>"
?>
```

Form and submit button:

```
<form action="/schedulelist/" method="post">

<button type="submit" id="slistSave" style="width:120px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="submit" value="save"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save</button>
```

Comment: Form tags? Submit button? I'm assuming you've just omitted them, but could you add them please.

Comment: Your JS is ready for XSS

Comment: @bub the JS is strictly for DEBUGGING. Will be removed once fixed.. obviously as i stated above.

Comment: Try  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $messagere . '");</script>';

Comment: Its nothing to do with the echo alert as i have other posts working. Anyway i solved it and am currently writing the solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue:

For some strange reason, it did not like the fact of having a name on the input tag as it would not post the value.. I do have names on other input tags and that worked perfectly with posting so i think its down to the label tag surrounding it?

The fix:

What i ended up doing was create a hidden section in which i can manipulate the values with some javascript with some if statements and it worked a charm!

Code:

JS:

```
<script>
function checkSelectedScheduleType<?PHP echo $line;?>()
{
    if (document.getElementById('radioSelected<?PHP echo $line;?>').value == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById('slradioEndResult<?PHP echo $line;?>').value = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {   
        document.getElementById('slradioEndResult<?PHP echo $line;?>').value = 0;
    }
}
</script>
```

Remember, i am echoing mine and not showing the full code ;)

```
echo" <td class=\"alarmvalue\" style=\"padding:2px 15px; display:none;\">
    <select name=\"line[$line][alarmEndSelectedResult]\" id=\"playlist_wrongstyle\" class=\"form-control\"  style=\"visibility:visible; text-align: center; background: transparent; width:250px;\">
        <option id=\"slradioEndResult$line\"></option>
    </select>
</td> "
```

Then called the JS function after it was generated everytime..
Hope it helps someone!